# Convert HTML to Django Fixture (JSON)

Tags: python, django, json

We've got a couple of Django flatpages in our project, that are based on actual HTML files. These files undergo some changes once in a while and hence have to updated in the database. So I came up with the idea of simply copying the plain HTML text into a JSON fixture and do an `manage.py loaddata`.

However, the problem is, that there are quite some characters inside the HTML that have to be escaped in order to pass as JSON. Is there some script, [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) command or maybe even an official Django solution for that problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could [write your own manage.py command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands) to read in the HTML file and adding them to the flatpages:

```
#  Assuming variable html contains the new HTML file,
#+ and var id the ID of the flatpage.
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
fp = FlatPage.objects.get (id=id)
fp.content = html
fp.save()
```